# Trouble sending a file to Imgur

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data, imgur

I'm trying to use the [python requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) to upload an image to Imgur using the [imgur api](http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon#upload). The api returns a 400, saying that the file is either not a supported file type or is corrupt. I don't think the image is corrupt (I can view it fine locally), and I've tried `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, and `.png`. Here is the code:

```
api_key = "4adaaf1bd8caec42a5b007405e829eb0"
url = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"
r = requests.post(url, data={'key': api_key, 'image':{'file': ('test.png', open('test.png', 'rb'))}})
```

The exact error message:

```
{"error":{"message":"Image format not supported, or image is corrupt.","request":"\/2\/upload.json","method":"post","format":"json","parameters":"image = file, key = 4adaaf1bd8caec42a5b007405e829eb0"}}
```

Let me know if I can provide more information. I'm pretty green with Python, and expect it's some simple misstep, could someone please explain what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just guessing, but looking at the imgur api, it looks like image should be just the file data, while the requests library is wrapping it into a key value pair (hence why the response shows "image = file")

I'd try something like:

```
import base64
api_key = "4adaaf1bd8caec42a5b007405e829eb0"
url = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"
fh = open('test.png', 'rb');
base64img = base64.b64encode(fh.read())
r = requests.post(url, data={'key': api_key, 'image':base64img})
```

Comment: How do we get link to the file uploaded?

Comment: Had the same problem in Swift, but now it works. You are life saver!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried being explicit with something like the following?:

```
from base64 import b64encode

requests.post(
    url, 
    data = {
        'key': api_key, 
        'image': b64encode(open('file1.png', 'rb').read()),
        'type': 'base64',
        'name': 'file1.png',
        'title': 'Picture no. 1'
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want open('test.png','rb').read() since open('test.png','rb') is a file object rather than the contents of the file?

Comment: Good thought. Same error occurs. The code around `open()` is taken from the docs, too: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file