# Post file and data to API using Python

Tags: python, post, python-2.7, python-requests, face-recognition

I'm experimenting a bit with an API which can detect faces from an image. I'm using Python and want to be able to upload an image that specifies an argument (in the console). For example:

```
python detect.py jack.jpg
```

This is meant to send file **jack.jpg** up to the API. And afterwards print **JSON** response. Here is the documentation of the API to identify the face.

http://rekognition.com/developer/docs#facerekognize

Below is my code, I'm using Python 2.7.4

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Imports
import sys
import requests
import json
# Facedetection.py sends us an argument with a filename
filename = (sys.argv[1])
# API-Keys
rekognition_key = ""
rekognition_secret = ""
array = {'api_key': rekognition_key,
                'api_secret': rekognition_secret,
                'jobs': 'face_search',
                'name_space': 'multify',
                'user_id': 'demo',
                'uploaded_file': open(filename)
                }  

endpoint = 'http://rekognition.com/func/api/'
response = requests.post(endpoint, params= array)

data = json.loads(response.content)
print data
```

I can see that everything looks fine, but my console gets this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload.py", line 23, in <module>
    data = json.loads(response.content)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 383, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What does executing `print response.content` yield?

Comment: @aIKid That gave me an extremely long output. Not a good one, 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'. See link with full output.https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/6aa58e3c6923a0590a05/raw/ccc8456c3df1befa9ed55a27996ab6116be1831e/python+upload-log.python

Comment: That's `response.content`?? That's absolutely not a JSON..

Comment: @aIKid Maybe my code isn't the correct solution for this?

Comment: You're passing your POST parameters (from the `array` dictionary) as query parameters (using the `params` argument). You should use `requests.post(endpoint, data=array)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Success!

The question didn't contain good code. I used code from here:
[uploading a file to imgur via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244183/uploading-a-file-to-imgur-via-python)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Imports
import base64
import sys
import requests
import json
from base64 import b64encode
# Facedetection.py sends us an argument with a filename
filename = (sys.argv[1])
# API-Keys
rekognition_key = ""
rekognition_secret = ""
url = "http://rekognition.com/func/api/"

j1 = requests.post(
    url, 
    data = {
        'api_key': rekognition_key,
        'api_secret': rekognition_secret,
        'jobs': 'face_recognize',
        'name_space': 'multify',
        'user_id': 'demo',
        'base64': b64encode(open(filename, 'rb').read()),
    }
)

data = json.loads(j1.text)
print data
```

Now this: `python detect.py jack.jpg` returns the wanted JSON. Fully working.