# How to send local image to chat using incoming webhook

Tags: api, google-chat

Facing issue while send the local image to google chat room using web hook.

```
attachment = open("images.jpg", "rb")
bot_message = {"cards": [{ "sections": [{"widgets": [{"image": attachment}]}]}]}
print (bot_message)
message_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
```

Error:

> TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

Issue roots from `BufferedReader` not JSON serializable which is caused by image widget expecting a URL instead.

Alternative is that, you need to upload your file to an image hosting site first (e.g. imgur) and then use the url of the posted image to the image widget's image url. For this one, see [Imgur API docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/).

#### Reference:

- [Image Widget requiring URL](https://developers.google.com/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#image_widget)
- [uploading a file to imgur via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244183/uploading-a-file-to-imgur-via-python)

Comment: Many Thanks. is there possibilities to send locally stored images?

Comment: Based on the provided documentation and other posts here, I was not able to confirm if locally stored images are possible (right now, it is safe to assume it is impossible). You would have to upload the images to a image hosting site first via api and then use the link generated for that upload in your image widget parameter

Comment: hi @ManiBharathi, If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)